# can any one help me out of this list index out of bound error

Tags: java, apex

Hi am getting the below error

list out of bond error at line

```
String userId = leadUsrStr.split('_')[1]
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no `_` in your `String`.

Answer (score 1):

can you check one `if` condition as follows,

```
if(leadUsrStr.contains("_")){
   String userId = leadUsrStr.split("_")[1];
}
```

Comment: can u paste the value of the string leadUsrStr once ?

Comment: for(String leadUsrStr : leadUserIds){
        
        String leadId = leadUsrStr.split('_')[0];
        String userId = leadUsrStr.split('_')[1];
     

        
        LeadShare ld = new LeadShare(LeadId = leadId, UserOrGroupId = userId, LeadAccessLevel = 'Read');
        leadShares.add(ld);
        
     
      }

Comment: u are trying to split with "" instead of this u can give "_" if u need to split with _.